# Elasticsearch Ranking on aggregation based on AND and OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with multiple keywords with an aggregation on author ID.

I want the ranking to be based on combining must and should.

For example for query 'X', 'Y' the authors containing both 'X' and 'Y' in the document field should be ranked higher, followed by authors who have either 'X' or 'Y'.

Doing each of them (AND/OR) is easy, I need the idea/direction how to achieve both in one ES query.

The current query I have for both X and Y is:

```
GET /docs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "X",
            "fields": [
              "fulltext"
            ],
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Y",
            "fields": [
              "fulltext"
            ],
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "search-users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author.id.keyword",
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top-docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changing must to should change it to OR but I want the combination of both ranking authors with must a higher ranking in aggregation.

Comment: You should definitely show the current query you have

Comment: I've added it now. @Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of boosting results is by adding a `should` clause looking for both terms, like this.

```
GET /docs/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fulltext": "X Y",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fulltext": "X Y",
            "operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "search-users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author.id.keyword",
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top-docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it takes care of ranking within the aggregation but the original query still is with AND, for example authors who have just used the word "X" or "Y" aren't part of the result.

Comment: Thanks. that's a massive improvement with two slight practical problems.

1. The queries themselves "X" or "Y" can include a space within them, I would rather have a way to include multiple queries one by one rather than in one string. 

2. Would it also work while searching from multiple fields, like fulltext and author.bio?

Comment: 1. The space is not a problem you can put all the terms in a single string and they will all be analyzed. 2. You can use multi_match if you have several fields.